# Axios POST Method: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, post, http-status-code-405

I'm building a webapp with React and Flask and I have an issue with POST request.

This is my `app.py` file:

```
import sys
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

from models import User, Project, Image, db
from api import blueprints
from tools import format_email


app = Flask(__name__,
  static_folder='../build/static',
  template_folder="../build"
)

app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
db.init_app(app)
cors = CORS(app)
mail = Mail(app)

# Register the blueprints
for b in blueprints:
  app.register_blueprint(b)

@cross_origin
@app.route('/', defaults={'u_path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:u_path>')
def index(u_path=None):
  return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/api/process_email', methods=['POST'])
def process_email():
  print('plop')
  data = request.get_json()
  formated_email = format_email(
    data['firstname'],
    data['lastname'],
    data['email'],
    data['message']
  )
  msg = Message(formated_email['title'], sender='plop@gmail.com', recipients=['plop@gmail.com'])
  msg.body = formated_email['textbody']
  msg.html = formated_email['htmlbody']
  mail.send(msg)

  return 'done'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

In the `config.py` I have this set `CORS_HEADERS = 'Content-Type'`

When I test this with Postman, my email is sent without any issue. But from the app, I get a `405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED` response.

This is how I send the request:

```
axios.post(API_URL + 'process_email/', {
      "firstname": values.firstname,
      "lastname": values.lastname,
      "email": values.email,
      "message": values.message
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
      },
      withCredentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data)
      }, (error) => {
        toast.error("gneuuuu");
      })
      .catch(() => {toast.error("Oups! Something went wrong!")});
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Since I put a proxy in place, I don't see preflights request anymore.
I tried with a simple `fetch` or use `superagent` but issue is still here, and I clearly don't understand how CORS works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer: issue was in the way I was sending the request with axios. Instead of:

`axios.post(API_URL + 'process_email/', {...`

I have to remove the trailing / ! This works fine:

`axios.post(API_URL + 'process_email', {...`